# primary key ID gives me repeated " 0 " value with android app

Tags: android-sqlite

I try to make contactsApp with android , when I debug it the primary key repeat its value which is zero
*AND HERE IS THE* **SQLiteOpenHelper class** :

```
    // get all Contacts
    public List<Contact> getAllContact(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();    
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();    
        String selectAll = "SELECT * FROM " + Util.TABLE_NAME;    
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectAll , null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
               // HERE is where the error come...
                try{
                    if (cursor.getString(0) != null)
                     contact.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1) );
                contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                contactList.add(contact);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return contactList;
    }
```

at first the error was NonNullException at this line

> contact.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));

so I surround it with try catch then the app debug correctly but still gives wrong value for the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY id

the final result should be like

> ID: 1, Name 1 , 111111111
>
> ID: 2, Name 2 , 22222222
>
> ID: 3, Name 3 , 33333333
>
> ID: 4, Name 4 , 444444444

But I get this result..

> ID: 0, Name 1 , 111111111
>
> ID: 0, Name 2 , 22222222
>
> ID: 0, Name 3 , 33333333
>
> ID: 0, Name 4 , 444444444

after some searches I did not find any solution for that!

***So what should I do to fix it*** ??

**Thanks in advance!**

**EDIT**
The stack-trace :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.muhamad_galal.databaseintro, PID: 3947
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.muhamad_galal.databaseintro/com.example.muhamad_galal.databaseintro.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4077)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
                      at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                      at Data.DataBaseHandler$override.getAllContact(DataBaseHandler.java:141)
                      at Data.DataBaseHandler$override.access$dispatch(DataBaseHandler.java)
                      at Data.DataBaseHandler.getAllContact(DataBaseHandler.java)
                      at com.example.muhamad_galal.databaseintro.MainActivity$override.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
                      at com.example.muhamad_galal.databaseintro.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
                      at com.example.muhamad_galal.databaseintro.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4077) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Read this...   https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Now, debug your code and print out all the SQL that's being executed.  The create table, the insert statements and the select statement.  Do they look correct?  If so, edit your question and include only the SQL *(if the SQL looks right, the code you've included is irrelevant)*.  If the code looks wrong, try to work out what's causing it.  But, as written, your question has too much superfluous information.  Narrow down the problem, make a minimal complete verifiable example  and take it from there. *(besides, that's good debugging practice)*

Comment: Thanks for advice ... I've cut the code to its limit . And I still trying to solve it.

Comment: Using the try catch to catch the error will not fix the underlying issue. Remove the try/catch, rerun and then edit your question to include the stack-trace.

Comment: Done! Thanks for your tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the message is saying is that you've passed a null to the Integer's `parseInt` method.  as per :-

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
```

Thus it appears that the first column of the table has nulls.

At a guess you have not defined the column to be an alias of **rowid** and thus the column hasn't been given a unique integer value.

To be an alias of **rowid** it must be defined as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` (the latter is not recommended).

If you changed :-

```
public List<Contact> getAllContact(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();    
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();    
    String selectAll = "SELECT * FROM " + Util.TABLE_NAME;    
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectAll , null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
           // HERE is where the error come...
            try{
                if (cursor.getString(0) != null)
                 contact.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1) );
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            contactList.add(contact);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return contactList;
}
```

to (see the comments at the end of lines that start with `//<<<<`) :-

```
public List<Contact> getAllContact(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();    
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();    
    String selectAll = "SELECT rowid,* FROM " + Util.TABLE_NAME; //<<<< CHANGED    
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectAll , null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setId(cursor.getInt(0)); //<<<< CHANGED to use getInt
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(2)); //<<<< CHANGED to skip first column
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(3)); //<<<< CHANGED to skip first column
            contactList.add(contact);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return contactList;
}
```

Then I suspect that you would get the expected results.

- This gets the normally hidden actual **rowid** column as well as all the other columns; so there is an extra column at the start.

  - Note this assumes that you haven't defined the table using `WITHOUT ROWID`
- Really you should consider the id/rowid as a `long` but `int` will work as long as there aren't too many rows.

However, this should only be a temporary fix.

---

The full/permanent fix should be

1. Code the first column so that it is defined as an alias of **rowid** e.g. using `CREATE TABLE you_table_name (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, the_other_columns......` (this assumes that the column name is **ID**).
2. Delete the database by either uninstalling the App or by deleting the App's data.

   1. This assumes that you do not require the current data.
3. Change the **`contact`** class so that the **Id** member is **`long`** not `int`.
4. Change the getters and setters in the **`contact`** class (`setId` and I assume `getId`) so that the methods use **`long`** rather than `int`
5. Change any other uses of the Id member of the **`contact`** class to use **`long`**.
6. Change the `getAllContact` method to be

:-

```
public List<Contact> getAllContact(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();    
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();    
    String selectAll = "SELECT * FROM " + Util.TABLE_NAME;    
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectAll , null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setId(cursor.getInt(0)); 
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            contactList.add(contact);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return contactList;
}
```

7. delete the App's Data or uninstall the App.
8. rerun the App

Comment: First of all Thanks for your help.

Comment: Second , the first solution worked but IDE gives hint
**<result column>, ALL or DISTINCT expected , got 'rowid'**
permanently worked as well.
**Thanks again**

Comment: re ALL or DISTINCT neither is valid and will therefore be ALL so you could use `String selectAll = "SELECT ALL * FROM " + Util.TABLE_NAME;`